# Using the new Vaadin 8 feature "HTML Imports" to import polymer WebComponent - Only works in Google Chrome not in other Browsers

Tags: polymer, vaadin

We are trying to use the new Vaadin 8 Feature "HTML Import". Using Vaadin 8.14 and Polymer 2.

An example is provided by vaadin in "[Whats new in Vaadin 8](https://vaadin.com/framework/whatsnew)"

**It is pretty straight forward and easy to implement. I followed the steps and it worked in Google Chrome right away. Basically you can't do much wrong.**

**However it doesn't seem to work in any different browser.**

For example in firefox the console.log prints it is loading the script but then nothing happens and the page stays stuck in loading.

I included the most relevant code.

MyUI.java:

```
@Theme("mytheme")
public class MyUI extends UI 
{
    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) 
    {
        final HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();
        layout.addComponents(new GameCard("♣", "k"), new GameCard("♥", "q"));
        setContent(layout);
    }

    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false)
    public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }
}
```

GameCard.java:

```
@JavaScript("vaadin://bower_components/game-card/game-card.js")
@HtmlImport("vaadin://bower_components/game-card/game-card.html")
public class GameCard extends AbstractJavaScriptComponent 
{
    public GameCard(String symbol, String rank) 
    {
        callFunction("setCard", symbol, rank);
    }
}
```

game-card.js:

```
is2_GameCard = function () {
    var element = this.getElement();
    this.setCard = function (symbol, rank) {
        element.set("symbol", symbol);
        element.set("rank", rank);
    };
};
is2_GameCard.tag = "game-card";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found it out. Firefox needs to use the WebComponents Loader to work with WebCompnents at all. including it in the UI is enough to make it work!

```
@Theme("mytheme")
@JavaScript("vaadin://bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js")
public class MyUI extends UI 
{
    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) 
    {
        final HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();
        layout.addComponents(new GameCard("♣", "k"), new GameCard("♥", "q"));
        setContent(layout);
    }
    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false)
    public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a browser support bit on this page https://www.webcomponents.org/ only Blink browsers natively support HTML Imports.